Can an EC2 instance read the SSMSessionRunAs variable without enabling "Run As" support for Linux instances in AWS Session Manager
I'm working with EC2 instances in AWS and I need to configure AWS Systems Manager (SSM) Session Manager for specific login behaviors.
I have multiple EC2 instances in a region, and I want one specific instance to read the SSMSessionRunAs environment variable for a custom login behavior. I do not want to enable the "Run As" support for all EC2 instances in the region in system manager.
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
The one EC2 instance should read the SSMSessionRunAs variable, which will allow it to run under a specific user that I define.
The rest of the EC2 instances should use the default login behavior (the usual default user for the instance).
I want to avoid enabling the "Run As" feature for all Linux instances in the region to keep the configuration specific to this one instance.
Is it possible to read the SSMSessionRunAs variable on just one EC2 instance without enabling Run As support globally across all EC2 instances in the region?
Additional Context:
I do not want to change the configuration for all instances in the region to avoid unintended behavior.
I'm looking for a way to selectively apply this behavior without globally modifying the Session Manager settings.
Has anyone achieved this before, or can you provide guidance on how to implement such a setup in AWS Systems Manager?
